# Struts2 property values set but are displayed empty

Tags: jsp, struts2

Ok, I was just trying out this simple example: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-property-tag-example/. It's nothing but just setting a property in the pre-action and displaying that in the jsp. It worked for me, no issues here.

I just tried to add an interceptor that intercepts all the requests to the action and reference the new interceptor stack (default stack + new interceptor) the action configuration. Then the issue of displaying empty properties started. The properties set in the action class are no longer accessible in the jsp. Any idea why?

Here's my config:

```
<action name="propertyTagAction" class="com.mkyong.common.action.PropertyTagAction" >
  <result name="success">pages/property.jsp</result>
  <interceptor-ref name="customStack">
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
</action>

<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="customInterceptor" class="...">
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
  </interceptor>
  <interceptor-stack name="customStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="customInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

Comment: Could you show code for your `customInterceptor`.

Comment: Well, that would contain some code that can't be put on here. Basically, it contains an intercept method which will check for user access. If the check failed, the validation error message will be added to the message store interceptor (for later use). Otherwise the action will be invoked using: actionInvocation.invoke(). 

What do you expect to be in there that you think would have caused this?

Comment: Who knows, but apparently it's something to do with your interceptor or configuration. If you won't post a minimally failing example it'll be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
<interceptor-ref name="customStack">
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

to this

```
<interceptor-ref name="customStack">
    <param name="customInterceptor.operationMode">STORE</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

---

From the documentation, [**Interceptor Parameter Overriding**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-InterceptorParameterOverriding), Example n.2:

> The syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> <interceptor-name>.<parameter-name>
> ```

Comment: It was a long try... =D